# Is the Collatz conjecture in $\Sigma_1 / \Pi_1$?

Tags: logic, recreational-mathematics, computability

Prompted by some of the comments on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100158/what-interesting-open-mathematical-problems-could-be-solved-if-we-could-perform), I'm wondering if anything is known about the place of the Collatz Conjecture in the arithmetic hierarchy.  More specifically, is Collatz known to be equivalent to a $\Sigma_1$ or $\Pi_1$ statement?  It's obvious that it can be expressed in the second level of the hierarchy, as $\forall n\exists k . C^{(k)}(n) = 1$ (and I believe functional composition is $\Delta_0$, so the fact that we're using a slightly extended language here should be moot; we can encode the computational path involved in computing $C^{(k)}(n)$ as a finite sequence of integers and thus as a single integer by appropriate coding), but there doesn't seem to be any obvious way of expressing it as a first-level statement...

Comment: The Collatz Conjecture can be written as a conjunction: (A) every Collatz sequence is bounded, and (B) the only Collatz orbit is $(1,4,2)$.  Neither part is known to be true or false.  But it seems like (B) is in $\Pi_1$, since it can be written as $\forall{n,k}.(C^{(k)}(n)=n)\rightarrow(n=1\vee n=2\vee n=4)$.

Comment: @mjqxxxx: That looks right to me - (A) is definitely the tricky part, though, and it doesn't look to have an easy $\Pi_1$ formulation.  I saw a slightly-sketchy looking paper on the web that seemed to say that questions about similar sequences were $\Pi^0_2$-complete and I seem to recall results along those lines about 'multi-Collatz' sequences with more than one iterable function (maybe from John Conway?), so I suspect there may not be any known answer for this.

Comment: @mjqxxx: if we try to check (B) according to your last recipe, and if we are by accident on a divergent trajectory - isn't the result whether we are on an orbit or on a divergent trajectory not depending on the *answer* whether the current trajectory is in fact divergent?

Comment: The usual statement is $\Pi_2$, but since the Collatz conjecture is a sentence it is equivalent to either $0=1$ or $0=0$... (Assuming we're working in the standard model. If you're asking whether the conjecture is provably equivalent to a $\Pi_1$ or $\Sigma_1$ sentence over PA or ZFC, that's a different matter.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I don't know if this will help but I find this the simplest form of the conjecture to work with. You can write the conjecture $f(x)=3x+2^{v_2(x)}$ and the conjecture is $\forall x\in\mathbb{N_{>0}}\exists n:f^n(x)\in\langle2\rangle$ where $\langle2\rangle=\{1,2,4,8,16,32,\ldots\}$

Answer (score 11):

As suggested in my comment above, I will interpret your question as asking whether the Collatz conjecture is provably equivalent to a $\Pi_1$ or $\Sigma_1$ sentence over some base theory $T$. There are a variety of issues at stake depending on the outcome of the conjecture (in the standard model).

Case 0: *The Collatz conjecture is false because some Collatz sequence is periodic with a period other than $4,2,1$*. In that case, the Collatz conjecture is provably equivalent to $0=1$ over any theory with enough power to encode and decode the witnessing sequence up to its first repetition (e.g. PA or I$\Sigma_1$).

Case 1: *The Collatz conjecture is false because some Collatz sequence never repeats itself*. In that case, the conjecture is perhaps equivalent to a $\Pi_1$ sentence. To say that the Collatz sequence starting with some standard number $n_0$ is never repeating is a $\Pi_1$ statement. In the strange scenario where the Collatz sequences that don't repeat are precisely the ones that go through $n_0$, then the Collatz conjecture is equivalent to that $\Pi_1$ statement. More generally, if there is a (standard) finite list $n_0,n_1,\dots,n_k$ such that the Collatz sequences that don't repeat are precisely those that go through one of these, then we also have a $\Pi_1$ sentence equivalent to the Collatz conjecture. Still more generally, if there is a computable sequence $n_0,n_1,\dots$ with that property, we also have a $\Pi_1$ sentence equivalent to the Collatz conjecture. However, if no such computable sequence exists then it is unlikely that we can do better than $\Sigma_2$ unless we use a non-axiomatizable base theory like the $\Pi_1$ theory of the standard model.

Case 2: *The Collatz conjecture is true*. In that case, the Collatz conjecture is equivalent to the statement that $g(n) = (\mu k)(C^k(n)=1)$ is a total computable function. We can then compare $g$ to various levels of the [fast-growing hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy) for a more precise analysis. For example, if $g(n)$ is bounded above by some $f_k$ where $k$ is finite, then $g$ is actually primitive recursive and the Collatz conjecture is provably true in I$\Sigma_1$ (same as PA except that induction is restricted to $\Sigma_1$ formulas). If $g(n)$ is abounded above by some $f_\alpha$ with $\alpha \lt \varepsilon_0$, then the Collatz conjecture is provably true in PA. If $g$ grows faster than that then a still stronger theory is required to prove the Collatz conjecture.

Comment: For every Collatz sequence going through $n_0$ that doesn't terminate, there are in fact infinitely many non-terminating sequences which don't go through $n_0$ so it looks like $\sum_2$ is the case if it's false (which it is almost certainly not). I can easily prove this by showing you that $\{4^m\cdot n_0+\tfrac{4^m-1}{3}:m\in\Bbb N\}$ all go to the same successor as $n_0$ - and they could never pass through $n_0$ as to do so would contradict the assumption that $n_0\ldots$ does not terminate (is not a loop).

Answer (score 0):

I've never dealt much with the question of divergent trajectories (condition *(A)* in *mjqxxx*'s comment), but the question of existence of orbits (condition *(B)*)  can be translated into a question, whether finite sets $\small E_N $ of *N* integer parameters $\small \left<A,B,C,\ldots,H \right> $ where $\small A,B,\ldots,H>0 $ admit a rational solution of a related system of linear equations.
*(Note: that parameters are used as exponents in the ["Syracuse"-formulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Syracuse_function) of the Collatz-problem:* $\small x_{k+1}=(3x_k +1)/2^A $ where $\small x_k $ *is odd and A is such, that also $\small x_{k+1} $ is odd)*.

If we denote the number of the above parameters as *N* and their sum as *S* then *N* and *S* must be in a (not exact, but tight) relation, for instance $\small 1.5 N < S< 2N $ so the values of the parameters for any set $\small E_N $ are upper-bounded.

Moreover, the number of parameters, which equal *1* versus that which exceed *1* is related by the fact, that the *1* -parameters represent rising and *>1*-parameters represent falling steps in the "Syracuse"-notation

Then the question of the existence of nontrivial cycles of any specified length *N* can be solved by enumeration and the check of solutions:  "has the solution integer value?" of the associated linear equation which has the form $\small x={Q(A,B,C,...,H) \over 2^S-3^N}$ where $\small Q(\ldots) $ is a linear composition of powers of *3* and *2* with exponents made from the parameters *A,B,...,H*. The amount of computation for each *N* is then limited by the number of combinatorical choices to satisfy the mentioned limitations for the set of *N* parameters . This is a kind of problem which can be solved by a supertask-machine because it is subfactorial for each *N* .

(I've done a related discussion about the existence of cycles in that "Syracuse"-view of the problem and the relation to the linear equation myself, but a more professional discussion of this point of view and the description of the equation (and for some specific types of cycles of a complete *system* of linear equations) is done for instance by John Simons 2007, one example [online here](http://www.rug.nl/staff/j.l.simons/MoCarticlem2.pdf) or even better here in an updated joint article with Benne de Weger 2010, which I just found [here](http://deweger.xs4all.nl/papers/%5B35a%5DSidW-3n+1-v1.44%5B2010%5D.pdf))